# How to call functions with names separated with numbers? Example calling function from t1 to t20 - Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium

```
def t17():
    Clientbox = 'body > table:nth-child(6) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > form 
    > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > 
    tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > 
    td:nth-child(2) > select'
    Clientname = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(Clientbox)
    Clientname.send_keys('Southern')

def t18():
    Clientbox = 'body > table:nth-child(6) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > form 
    > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > 
    tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > 
     td:nth-child(2) > select'
    Clientname = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(Clientbox)
    Clientname.send_keys('Star')



t3() Thenewway() InspectTickets() newticket() t4() Thenewway() InspectTickets() newticket() t5() Thenewway() I

nspectTickets()
```

Is there a better way to do this? With a loop probably. New to python. Thanks in advcance!

Answer (score 2):

The *obvious* solution is to not define a bunch of functions and then try to call them by name. This is the same problem of variable variable names: they lead to unmaintainable code. There are almost always better overall approaches that let you use natural language constructs (enumerated variables or functions aren't natural).

If you insist on having a huge number of functions (but you should refactor your code to avoid this), you could append all the functions into a list and call them each:

```
all_funs = []

def foo(args):
    return 'hello'
all_funs.append(foo)

# ...
for fun in all_funs:
    # call the function in a loop
    print(fun())
```

Or I could imagine a decorator that collects the function into a container for you.

Either way you will have to do some extra work, since you are trying to do something forceful in python. The good thing about this language is that straightforward things are very easy to do, so if you see yourself exerting a lot of seemingly unnecessary work then you probably *are* doing unnecessary work. Take a few steps back and try to rewrite your code to be more natural. for instance, `t17` and `t18` only differ in a single string passed to `.send_keys`. You should make this an input parameter and use the same function. I'm certain most of your 20 functions can be simplified the same way to use one or two underlying functions.

Answer (score 0):

Andras Deak answer is perfect.
I put my answer in just in hope to understand your problem (and question) even better.
Looking at your functions, it seems you need, for a single element obtained by

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector
```

to send a string into a text box

if you just need to send different string, into the very SAME text box (it seems to me that you point at the same element in the two example fun you attached), then you DON'T need to use many functions, exactly as Andras said.

just use a for loop:

```
def t17():
    Clientbox = 'body > table:nth-child(6) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > form 
> table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > 
tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > 
td:nth-child(2) > select'
    Clientname = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(Clientbox)
    # example list:
    key_list = ["Southern", "Star"]
    for key in key_list:
        Clientname.send_keys(key)
```

Of course, if you need it, don't forget to send also the ENTER KEY:

```
# this at top of the file:
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# in yout function:
Clientname.send_keys(Keys.ENTER))
```

And if you should need to wait the page reloading, then also use the Wait method from Selenium library:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import wait as Wait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    Wait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector(Clientbox).is_displayed())
except TimeoutException as e:
    print("here handle your exception", e)
```

This will wait a maximum of 10 seconds (you can  of course custom it!) then it'll throw a TimeoutException, making clear that the element you want (or even the whole page) has not been loaded

I hope I get the point of your question and that this helps.

---

If you absolutely need to call functions by a number (or by a choosen name) then you could try to use a dictionary, which offers more control than a list if you do not need, everytime, to loop the whole listed items:

```
def d1():
    return "it's d1"


def d2():
    return "it's d2"


def d3():
    return "it's d3"


def d4():
    return "it's d4"


def fun_switcher(num):
    switcher = {1: d1, 2: d2, 3: d3}
    return switcher.get(num, lambda: "fun address error")

# execution example:
if __name__ == "__main__":

    num = 2
    result = fun_switcher(num)
   # remember to call the function, or you will get the function_object as result!
    print(result())
```